# hii i am using temboo for iot using ethernet shield and arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

i am geting this error.

Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

IoT_test_sketch.ino:10:65: fatal error: TembooAccount.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Temboo.

It looks like you're missing the TembooAccount.h file that contains your Temboo account info. You can learn about it in our getting started tutorial (see steps 10 & 11):

https://temboo.com/arduino/others/getting-started

Hopefully this helps. If you have any questions, feel free to contact us at https://temboo.com/contact

Comment: Thanksss for your reply i had figured out the problem and solved it.... but now i am uploading the yahooWhethercheck code on my uno and ethernet shield but on the serial monitor it says    DHCP:FAIL what should i do??